# How to add border to custom marker icon in Angular2, agm-marker?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

[image]

Hi everyone, I need help in this. I am trying this from yesterday. Actually my requirement is to add custom marker icons dynamically to each lat/lng and there are additional values with each marker icon like a "color name" which I have to use as border color.
In agm-marker I can set url and icon height/width in [iconUrl] as

```
[iconUrl]='{
  "url":  imgurl, 
  "scaledSize": {
      "height": 100, 
      "width": 100
  }
}'
```

but I unable to find anything in which I can add border to the marker icon. 
However I have done this before using Rickmarker script in javascript.
Below is the screenshot of desired output
[image]

Comment: `google.maps.Icon` doesn't have a border property. You could generate your images server side to include that border.

Answer (score 0):

> ISSUE RESOLVED :)

**[agm-overlays](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-overlays)**

It helped me to achieve required output. Thanks to the developer.